# Tesla coil is arcing across the secondary

Tags: tesla-coil

I built a spark gap Tesla coil and it works great but I have two problems.

1. My secondary coils is arcing, from the bottom mostly, but also other places and it is damaging the secondary. Is there a solution to this?
2. I don't use a top load but I have a breakout point.  Not all of the arcs are coming out of the breakout point. Is there a way to have all the arcs come out of the breakout point?

Here's a list of everything I used:

- secondary coil: 1200 turns, 3.5 inches wide, 13 inches tall and 30 AWG wire
- capacitor bank/mmc: 18.8 nF. 20 kV
- neon sign transformer: 10 kV, 50 mA, 50 Hz
- primary coil: 6.5 turns, wire diameter 0.27 inches
- static spark gap 0.3 inches

Comment: This is more for a specialized coiler site but have you grounded your secondary?  Is it coated in enamel/lacquer?

Comment: Where's it arcing to/from? Is it arcing over, or corona discharge? Is it arcing to the primary?
Coating it with lacquer _might_ help (at least it'll make it sturdier / prevent unwinding, so always worth it), but for more help we'll need more details.

Comment: Thanks for anserwing. It is mistet arcing from t bottom of the secondary to the bottom. Its a 2 inch arc. And its the same place. Also somtimes it arcs across the Hole coil, from top to buttom. So 13 inches